# Passing user information in Authorization header to api

Tags: api, rest, encryption, authorization, hmac

I want to allow/prevent access of users to certain actions based on their role (admin, user, maybe something else) and id (users can only modify resources they own).

I do not want to load user profile in every API call, I want this information passed in request headers somehow.

I am considering two approaches:

1. User's access token contains both the required user information and time period (aes encrypted). The token is passed in Authorization header in every request. Server decrypts the token and gets all the information from it.
2. User's access token has the same information hashed (with HMAC). Authorization header contains both the token and the required user information (ID, role, maybe username). Server hashes user's information together with the current period using the same secret and compares with the passed token. If they are equal the access is granted.

Which approach is more secure (I feel the 2nd) and more common (probably the 1st)?

If you think the approach 2 is better, is it maybe better to pass user's information in a separate header?